# Deferred binding failed for GWTP PlaceManager

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, guice, gwt-gin, gwtp

This is the error I get when running my application:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for
>   'com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.PlaceManager' (did you forget to
>   inherit a required module?)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:97)
>       at com.myapp.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.create_Key$type$com$gwtplatform$mvp$client$proxy$PlaceManager$_annotation$$none$$(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:597)
>       at com.myapp.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.get_Key$type$com$gwtplatform$mvp$client$proxy$PlaceManager$_annotation$$none$$(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:611)
>       at com.myapp.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.getPlaceManager(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:27)
>       at com.myapp.client.MainAppEntryPoint.onModuleLoad(MainAppEntryPoint.java:17)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log
>   entries)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:503)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:97)
>       at com.myapp.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.create_Key$type$com$gwtplatform$mvp$client$proxy$PlaceManager$_annotation$$none$$(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:597)
>       at com.myapp.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.get_Key$type$com$gwtplatform$mvp$client$proxy$PlaceManager$_annotation$$none$$(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:611)
>       at com.myapp.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.getPlaceManager(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:27)
>       at com.myapp.client.MainAppEntryPoint.onModuleLoad(MainAppEntryPoint.java:17)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Although I have these on the `.gwt.xml` file:

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.inject.Inject"/>
<inherits name='com.gwtplatform.mvp.Mvp'/>
<inherits name='com.gwtplatform.dispatch.Dispatch'/>

<define-configuration-property name='gin.ginjector' is-multi-valued='false' />
<set-configuration-property name='gin.ginjector' value='com.myapp.client.gin.ClientGinjector' />
```

In the application `WEB-INF/lib`:

```
guice-assistedinject-3.0-rc2.jar
guice-servlet-3.0.jar
guice-3.0.jar  
gin-1.5.0.jar
gin-1.5-post-gwt-2.2.jar
gwtp-all-0.7.jar
```

What could be missing?

Comment: when I see this exception I usually check gwt compilation logs for missing sources.

Comment: can you post your ginmodule file